# route to tabs on ionic1, Could someone help me with this route to the tabs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Doubt about route for tabs on ionic 1
I have a main screen that has the following route:

```
.state('app.principal', {
    url: '/principal',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/principal.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

In the page main.html I have a button that will access the route of tabs, that this button:

```
<ion-item class="col text-center">
                  <img class="botao" src="img/placeholder.png" ui-sref="app.tab"></img>
                  <br>Comunidades e <br>Paroquia<br>
                </ion-item>
```

My route to the tabs:

```
.state ('tab', {
     Url: '/ tab',
     Abstract: true,
     TemplateUrl: 'templates / tabs.html'
   })

     .state ('tab.communities', {
       Url: '/communities',
       Views: {
         'Tab-communities': {
           TemplateUrl: 'templates / tab-communities.html',
         }
       }
     })
   .state ('tab.map', {
     Url: '/map',
     Views: {
       'Tab-map': {
         TemplateUrl: 'templates / tab-map.html',
       }
     }
   })
```

But the route in my button is not working, when I press the button to go to the other screen and show the screen with the tabs appearing this error:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'app.tab' from state 'app.principal'
    At Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js: 52018)
    At Object.go (ionic.bundle.js: 51951)
    At ionic.bundle.js: 53001
    At ionic.bundle.js: 32328
    At completeOutstandingRequest (ionic.bundle.js: 19199)
    At ionic.bundle.js: 19475
```

Could someone help me with this route to the tabs?

Comment: you have a link going to a state that doesn't exist. "app.tabs". Your state is named "tabs"

Comment: As I say I changed the tab to tabs and then I did some tests, and my route looks like this:
.state ('tabs', {
     Url: '/ tab',
     Abstract: true,
     Controller: 'TabsCtrl',
     TemplateUrl: 'templates / tabs.html'

   })

     .state ('unit_tabs', {
       Url: '/ community',
       Views: {
         'Community tab': {
           TemplateUrl: 'templates / tab-community.html',
         }
       }
     })

Comment: <img class="botao" src="img/placeholder.png" ui-sref="app.tab"></img> This app.tab doesn't exist. At least not in the code you showed us

Comment: @yBrodsky  Thanks a lot for the tip, but now there's another problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yyd42kr9tr3m48w/sidemenu.png?dl=0, the top menu is not appearing and my sidemenu is not.

Comment: The problem is that the abstract state "tab" should be itself a nested state for app. I am assuming app is an abstract state that contains your navbar.

Comment: Would you have an example? @yBrodsky

Comment: I dont have any example that might be useful in your case. Why dont you put all your routes in a pastebin and show it to me. Maybe it will be easier to sort it out and find the mistake

Comment: @yBrodsky Thanks a lot for the help. I managed to post it as I did here.

Comment: That was not clear. What do you mean?

Comment: I got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work that way.

```
.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
  })
    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  /*  .state('tabs', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'

  })*/

    .state('app.tabs', {
    url: '/tab',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      }
    }
  })
   .state('app.tabs.comunidade', {
      url: '/comunidade',
      views: {
        'tab-comunidade': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-comunidade.html',
          controller : 'ParksCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
   .state('app.tabs.comunidade-detail', {
      url: '/comunidade/:parkId',
      views: {
        'tab-comunidade': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-detail.html',
          controller : 'ComunidadeDetailController'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('app.tabs.map', {
    url: '/map',
    views: {
      'tab-map': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-map.html',
        controller: 'MapController'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.missa', {
    url: '/missa',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/missa.html'
      }
    }
  })
```